# Data is not coming from the database while running the windows phone 8 application

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8

This is Basina, new to windows phone development.

I'm using SQLite in my Windows Phone8 Application following the below article.
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone

When I debug the application I'm able to successfully created the database and tables.

After that i successfully installed the records into the table and retrieved the result and showed in a list.

After that I stopped the debugging of the application.

Now I run the application.

When I retrieve the data from the database and try to show the data in the list,

the list was empty i.e. data is not added to the list.

I didn't understand what was the problem.

While debugging the application everything goes fine, But while running the app i'm not getting data and also not showing any errors too.

I'm looking forward for your response.

Thanks & Regards,

Basina.

Comment: Please put your code to know exactly what's your problem is?

Comment: Did you uninstall you app from device or emulator?

Comment: I didn't uninstall the app. I just stop the debugging. I'm using the emulatior not the device.

Comment: what changes have you done till now mail me the full code i will try to figure that out...

Comment: @SureshBasina You have to put your code for better help

Answer (score 0):

actually this is sqlite time connection  issue. when you debug your app then thr is enough time for the sqlite to make successful connection but when you actually run this time is very less and when you made a query at that time the connection is not established so thr is  no data in the list. so what you can do is..make the static connection at the  start of your app and use this connection throughout app cycle .

Comment: I have solved the above issue. There was wrong logic written in my code. I've changed the logic now everything goes fine.

Comment: above part is what i have used for my sqlite connection it above piont can be happen with you. just think the above way i have used it in my app(delhi-ncr metro for wp8) too it's just working fine.